# part from split string with muliple delimites python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am programing with Python 2.7 and need to take only the numbers from a string which looks like that:

```
str=lat/lng: (33.17266673943457,36.14166408777237),lat/lng: (30.354898307940665,33.88161934912205)
```

I can't use

```
str[from:to]
```

beacuse the length of those numbers changes.

I have tried to use

```
print re.split('\(,\)', str)
```

and

```
filter(None, re.split("(,]+", str))
```

but I am not getting the results as I need.
Thank you very much!
Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to do the match, not the split:

```
> str= "str=lat/lng: (33.17266673943457,36.14166408777237),lat/lng: (30.354898307940665,33.88161934912205)"

> numbers = re.findall(r"(-*\d+\.\d+)", str)

> numbers
['33.17266673943457',
 '36.14166408777237',
 '30.354898307940665',
 '33.88161934912205']
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that after I posted and did an edit. It wasn't technically asked for but I believe coordinates can be negative.

Comment: Thank you it really helps me!! especially with negative coordintates

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall("\(([\d\.]+)\s*,\s*([\d\.]+)\)",s)
```

I think should work

```
>>> s = "lat/lng: (33.17266673943457,36.14166408777237),lat/lng: 30.354898307940665,33.88161934912205)"
>>> re.findall("\((-?[\d\.]+)\s*,\s*(-?[\d\.]+)\)",s)
[
   ('33.17266673943457', '36.14166408777237'), 
   ('30.354898307940665', '33.88161934912205')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex:

```
import re
coords="lat/lng: (33.17266673943457,36.14166408777237),lat/lng: (30.354898307940665,33.88161934912205)"
coords = re.sub("[a-z/: ()]+", '', coords).split(",")
# ['33.17266673943457', '36.14166408777237', '30.354898307940665', '33.88161934912205']
```

Comment: `[^\d\.]+` ? maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to stick with `.split()` instead of having to import `re` you could use the following:

```
str = 'lat/lng: (33.17266673943457,36.14166408777237),lat/lng: (30.354898307940665,33.88161934912205)'
print( [ s.strip(',').strip(')').split(',') for s in str.split('lat/lng: (') if s ] )
```

Returns:

```
[['33.17266673943457', '36.14166408777237'], ['30.354898307940665', '33.88161934912205']]
```